# Variable Type convention for binary or yes/no variables in Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, binary

IOS novice with PHP background learning core data here.

What variable type is best practice for binary i.e. Yes/No or True/False values in core data?

In PHP the convention is to use tinyint or 0,1.  Core data seems to have a Boolean primitive but you can also use NSNumber, int etc.

I'm currently using Boolean as the variable type in the .xcdatamodel file but am running into a lot of problems capturing binary variables from switches, trying to do if else comparisons and so forth so would like to do it the right way.  Thx.

Answer (score 0):

CoreData's BOOL type is not a "real" boolean, since boolean is not an object. You should store them as NSNumber and convert them to boolean.

set:

```
[entity setBinary:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
```

get:

```
BOOL isBinaryOn = [[entity binary] boolValue];
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: So in the xcdatamodel file I should make the type NSNumber? In the above example, I see the entity but where does the attribute name go? Also will this work with key value coding such as [record setValue:pub forKey:@"pub"]; if pub is an attribute of type NSNumber with value 1 or 0?  Finally, when doing comparisons can I say if(self.entity.pub==1) again where pub is attribute?

Comment: "binary" is the attribute name. Key value coding should work the same way. 
On the last question, yes it would work, or you can convert the self.entity.pub attribute into a boolean and use that in the if statement.